# Passing variables in https url

Tags: php, magento, url, https

I am trying to pass a value with a url which goes to a login page. The login page has a https url and when I follow the link it removes the variable at the end. So for example the url starts off as

```
   https://website.com/login?myvalue
```

The link works and the url still contains the value when I get to the page but by the time the page has finished loading the value is gone. The url becomes:

```
   https://website.com/login
```

Is it not possible to pass a value with a https url or am I just doing it wrong?
All help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want so then use session variable

Comment: is it remove myvalue from url or do you want to remove it?

Comment: ideally it should be working, are you sure you haven't set any url route in your htaccess?

Comment: it is removing it and i don't want it to. I just want to know if it can be done

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php

Comment: Do you have any re-write rules (apache/.htaccess or within magento)? Maybe SEO friendly URLS?

Comment: @TecBrat I'm checking but can't find any. Also asked another dev who has worked on the site and he reckoned no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a redirect over-writing the url. I had to use session variables in the end unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Surely you should assign a value to the urlURL variable myvalue?

```
https://website.com/login?myvalue=yes
```

I haven't worked with HTTPS, only HTTP, but it should work the same unless they don't allow request variables.

Comment: The existence of a param is enough to signify what needs to be done. What that value is, isn't important

Comment: just use session variables then

Comment: I'm aware of session variables and what they can do. I just want to know the answer to this